# How to check Serial number of RAM and built date. windows 7

Tags: windows-7, serial-number

I am suspicious about the RAM upgraded(not sure whether the person added new or used). i.e. I want to check serial number of the RAM with built date.

**Platform**-Windows 7.

I tried this with '**wmic** memorychip get serialnumber' but **it shows blank**.

[image: Power shell screen shot]

--Output of Get-WmiObject -Class win32_physicalmemory | fl *

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

WARNING: File C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDiagnostics\PSDiagnostics.psm1 cannot be loaded
because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject -Class win32_physicalmemory | fl *


__GENUS              : 2
__CLASS              : Win32_PhysicalMemory
__SUPERCLASS         : CIM_PhysicalMemory
__DYNASTY            : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH            : Win32_PhysicalMemory.Tag="Physical Memory 0"
__PROPERTY_COUNT     : 30
__DERIVATION         : {CIM_PhysicalMemory, CIM_Chip, CIM_PhysicalComponent, CIM_PhysicalElement...}
__SERVER             : PRAKASH-VAIO
__NAMESPACE          : root\cimv2
__PATH               : \\PRAKASH-VAIO\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMemory.Tag="Physical Memory 0"
BankLabel            : Bank 0
Capacity             : 4294967296
Caption              : Physical Memory
CreationClassName    : Win32_PhysicalMemory
DataWidth            : 64
Description          : Physical Memory
DeviceLocator        : SODIMM1
FormFactor           : 12
HotSwappable         :
InstallDate          :
InterleaveDataDepth  :
InterleavePosition   :
Manufacturer         :
MemoryType           : 0
Model                :
Name                 : Physical Memory
OtherIdentifyingInfo :
PartNumber           :
PositionInRow        :
PoweredOn            :
Removable            :
Replaceable          :
SerialNumber         :
SKU                  :
Speed                :
Status               :
Tag                  : Physical Memory 0
TotalWidth           : 64
TypeDetail           : 4
Version              :
Scope                : System.Management.ManagementScope
Path                 : \\PRAKASH-VAIO\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMemory.Tag="Physical Memory 0"
Options              : System.Management.ObjectGetOptions
ClassPath            : \\PRAKASH-VAIO\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMemory
Properties           : {BankLabel, Capacity, Caption, CreationClassName...}
SystemProperties     : {__GENUS, __CLASS, __SUPERCLASS, __DYNASTY...}
Qualifiers           : {dynamic, Locale, provider, UUID}
Site                 :
Container            :

__GENUS              : 2
__CLASS              : Win32_PhysicalMemory
__SUPERCLASS         : CIM_PhysicalMemory
__DYNASTY            : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH            : Win32_PhysicalMemory.Tag="Physical Memory 1"
__PROPERTY_COUNT     : 30
__DERIVATION         : {CIM_PhysicalMemory, CIM_Chip, CIM_PhysicalComponent, CIM_PhysicalElement...}
__SERVER             : PRAKASH-VAIO
__NAMESPACE          : root\cimv2
__PATH               : \\PRAKASH-VAIO\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMemory.Tag="Physical Memory 1"
BankLabel            : Bank 1
Capacity             : 2147483648
Caption              : Physical Memory
CreationClassName    : Win32_PhysicalMemory
DataWidth            : 64
Description          : Physical Memory
DeviceLocator        : SODIMM2
FormFactor           : 12
HotSwappable         :
InstallDate          :
InterleaveDataDepth  :
InterleavePosition   :
Manufacturer         :
MemoryType           : 0
Model                :
Name                 : Physical Memory
OtherIdentifyingInfo :
PartNumber           :
PositionInRow        :
PoweredOn            :
Removable            :
Replaceable          :
SerialNumber         :
SKU                  :
Speed                :
Status               :
Tag                  : Physical Memory 1
TotalWidth           : 64
TypeDetail           : 4
Version              :
Scope                : System.Management.ManagementScope
Path                 : \\PRAKASH-VAIO\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMemory.Tag="Physical Memory 1"
Options              : System.Management.ObjectGetOptions
ClassPath            : \\PRAKASH-VAIO\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMemory
Properties           : {BankLabel, Capacity, Caption, CreationClassName...}
SystemProperties     : {__GENUS, __CLASS, __SUPERCLASS, __DYNASTY...}
Qualifiers           : {dynamic, Locale, provider, UUID}
Site                 :
Container            :



PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: cpu z may get you the serial numbers but its best to just read the stickers on the sticks. If they are covered by a heatsink just be careful not to knock any components off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPUID's CPUZ does it, see the SPD Tab:
http://www.cpuid.com/
http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/cpu-z/cpu-z_1.75-en.zip

edit:
I was curious now and googled a lot to see what seems to be the limits of writing some hardware inventory scripts including powershell and .NET /C#.
Obviously it is "safe" to read the information from the SMBIOS which include nearly everything from the DRAM SPD **except** the manufactured date.
CPUZ seems to hack over SMBUS/I2C(?) being very close to hardware to get the date, which is not supported by MS for my understanding.

For everyone with some dev experience, I'd recommend to check this nice project with full source. Besides many sensors it also reads the SMBIOS like the Class win32_physicalmemory does. Despite the powershell script, it needs elevated user rights.
https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor

Comment: -Isn't there a windows utility(given by microsoft)?

Comment: I am not aware of. But the Powershell Script is Very close

Answer (score 2):

Use Powershell to query for the serialnumbers of your RAM memory, unfortunately the creation date is not avaiable with PowerShell.

Take a look at this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_physicalmemory | select manufacturer, serialnumber

manufacturer     serialnumber
------------     ------------
Kingston         97183***
Kingston         97187***
Kingston         9F181***
Kingston         98189***
```

Use `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_physicalmemory | fl *` to check the various properties that the `win32_physicalmemory` class returns.  Maybe you can find some other useful stuff.

To check the serialnumbers of your RAM memory with CPU-Z, download it from [here](http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/cpu-z/cpu-z_1.75-en.exe). Install, and start the application.

Finally click on the `SPD` tab to view the serialnumber, creationdate, manufacturer etc.  With the slots pull-down menu you can select the modules present in your machine.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: I ran 'Get-WmiObject -Class win32_physicalmemory | select manufacturer, serialnumber' but its showing blank for both manufacturer as well as serialnumber

Comment: Probably a typo, can you post a screenshot in your opening post?

Comment: the entrys in the SPD of RAM Modules is not mandatory. especially cheaper modules often lack these deeper information

Comment: @FalcoAlexander-you mean RAM chips are available in market which lacks this information?

Comment: @doenoe- can u check if the command I entered in power shell(screen-shot added) is right?

Comment: Yup, it is. can you post the output of `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_physicalmemory | fl *` ?

Comment: @doenoe- posted the screen-shot for Get-WmiObject -Class win32_physicalmemory | fl *

Comment: The WMI get the data using the WMI providers, unfortunately some manufacturers doesn't expose such data to these providers so you are out luck here. I guess you have to use CPU-Z to get the information you are looking for.

Comment: @doenoe-I m entirely new to CPU-Z. Can you help me with the command?

Comment: @Prakash, I have editted my original answer. Don't forget to mark as answer for future references

Comment: @Prakash Yes, there are/were RAM Modules available that lack of some SPD details